# How to use arithmetic operators to get cell location

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to perform math within an Excel formula to specify the end of an array. Here is a simple version of what I want to do:

```
A      B                      C
1   =COUNTA(A1:A5)-1    =SUM(A1:A(1+B1))        
2       
3       
4       
5
```

The first column is my data array. The second column counts the number of entries in that array (so if it isn't full, it returns a value less than 5). The third column sums the array starting with the first value and ending with the last entered value. Obviously with the `SUM` function it doesn't matter if there are zeroes, but I am trying to use the `MATCH` function and I don't want it to return a zero just because there are blank entries in the array I'm looking up.

So I want to modify the information within the `SUM` function to produce a variable array length based on the return value of `B1`. I hope this is clear. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1:A"&(1+B1)))
```

Comment: I was about to post that one xD I'm still not used with using `INDEX` the way Barry does xP

Comment: @Jerry: I am used to both but I prefer the indirect way :)

Comment: There are some situations where INDIRECT is probably better (perhaps you definitely want to refer to column A even if columns are added) but more often I think INDEX is preferable - because you don't need to "hardcode" the column letters.....and it's not (as) volatile

Comment: @barryhoudini: You may be right about all that, barry, though for the moment I am preferring Sid's answer. Mostly what I was looking for was the proper syntax, and I didn't really understand how to use the & character in formulas. Modifying the INDIRECT function is working better for me because I was already using it to reference other sheets (named by another cell in the active sheet), and INDEX starts getting messy when I try to modify an array on another sheet with values taken from the active sheet.

Comment: No problem, use what suits the situation best - sometimes you just have to be careful with INDIRECT - if you overuse it then it can slow your worksheet down because every time you change something INDIRECT re-calculates

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use INDEX like this

`=SUM(A1:INDEX(A:A,B1+1))`

you can use the range defined by

`A1:INDEX(A:A,B1+1)`

in other functions like MATCH